# how to manage sql server 2008 that came with Visual studio 2008?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

i install visual-studio 2008, part ot the installation is the sql server 2005 express.

how i can manage this sql server ?

is there any visual tool for making tables ? run queries ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b) from Microsoft's homepage!

Comment: I don't think that it works on the express versions, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Sql Server Management Studio Express.  You can download it from Microsoft.com.